# Copy multiple items between dictionaries

Tags: python, performance, loops, dictionary, copy

I want to copy selected elements between dictionaries. Is there a better/more efficient way than this:

```
dict1 = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4}
list = ['a', 'd']

dict2 = { k : dict1[k] for k in dict1 if k in list }
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use `dict.get()` and iterate through the list of keys instead of the dictionary.

```
>>> {k:dict1.get(k) for k in list1}
{'a': 1, 'd': 4}
```

Note, you shouldn't override the built-in type `list`.

This is especially helpful as if `k` isn't a key in dict1, then `None` is returned.

Comment: you can also guard with `{k: dict1[k] for k in list1 if k in dict1}` depending whether you prefer to leave the keys out or assign them to `None`

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is:

```
 dict2 = { k : dict1[k] for k in list }
```

Comment: Simple solutions are sometimes too easy to overlook!

Comment: Watch out when using the id `list`, which is a Python built-in, though!

Comment: worth mentioning that dictionary comprehension is available from `2.7`

Comment: `get` would be better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There's the functional way

```
>>> dict1 = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4}
>>> lst = ['a', 'd']
>>> dict(zip(lst, map(dict1.get, lst)))
{'a': 1, 'd': 4}
```

or

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> dict(zip(lst, itemgetter(*lst)(dict1)))
{'a': 1, 'd': 4}
```

But they are ~3 times slower than the dict comprehension :)

Comment: -1, what's the point of mentioning/answering when OP explicitly mentioned "a better/more efficient way"?

Comment: Because sometimes it's helpful for _other_ users of the site.

Comment: [This seems a better option to do that.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Is really that more functional than a dictionary comprehension?